# Inconsistent offset and timestamp in kafka ConsumerRecord?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We have springboot app, which generates kafka ConsumerRecords. Two of them per rest endpoint 'invocation', within same tx, into same partition, using spring-kafka KafkaTemplate indirection. When debugging we can see that events are sent in order. (for the record: there is one more indirection via springboot event and transactional event listener, but every time I debug it, I can see them in order. And I will explain later, why I think this cannot be causing this behavior.) So: Event A is sent first, B second. Mostly it's fine, for years and hundreds millions of messages.

But now we noticed a problem, I cannot explain yet. When we try to read the topic, we are getting these 2 events in opposite order. Our debugging/support cli-tool uses just `consumer.poll` calls, and iterates over returned data. B goes first, A second. Looking into records properties:

```
ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> consumerRecord = ...
log offset = consumerRecord.offset();
long timestamp = consumerRecord.timestamp()
```

offset(B) < offset(A), which corresponds to order in which we got the data from `poll` call, BUT timestamp(A) < timestamp(B).

I cannot currently tell what is the configuration of `log.message.timestamp.type` if it's `CreateTime` or `LogAppendTime`, but I'd assume it's CreateTime.

Can someone explain how this can happen? How can record have higher offset, but smaller timestamp? Am I missing some fundamental kafka principle?

1. I'd expect that this should be impossible with `LogAppendTime` — time should be calculated on kafka side just as offset.
2. I read/debug whole our code and spring-boot code from start to kafkaTemplate call, and I totally don't believe, that there is possibility to change order or these records, which could be supported by correlating timestamps assuming CreateTime strategy is used.
3. I don't believe transactional spring events can influence it, since KafkaTemplate is called only from them, so even if CreateTime strategy is used, since listener is synchronous, single threaded, the time will be correlated to order in which events were processed.

UPDATE:
I just found this [link](https://aiven.io/blog/kafka-real-ordering) about ordering of messages. IIUC this means, that kafka preserves order per single partition, BUT from point of view of kafka server, not from clients point of view. You, as a client, does not have guarantee of kept order. IIUC the very first example of failure happened to us.

Comment: _You, as a client, does not have guarantee of kept order_. Sure you do - 1) use (Kafka, not Spring) transactions 2) limit `max.inflight.connections` 3) dont allow retries, which the documentation says can re-order data from producer requests during failure